# Ajax post to RESTful web service

Tags: java, ajax, rest

I am having an issue with an Ajax post to a RESTful web service in Java. The project utilizes a single servlet mvc model, with the Ajax post data being sent as JSON to the web service. The specific issue that is occuring is that I a unable to pull the data out of a HttpServletRequest object on the web service side. The POST goes directly to the web service, and I attempted to pull the data out with the following:

```
@Path(Ajax)
public AjaxResource(){
@Context
HttpServletRequest request;

@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response postMethod(){

BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
// additional code
}
}
```

I receive an IllegalStateException on the getReader() call on the request; from what I understand the input stream/reader can only be called once. I am unsure if this is due to the doPost method in the servlet doing a request.getParameter call as it seems to ago I'd hitting the servlet before this web service. Is there any other way to retrieve this data other than implementing HttpServletRequestWrapper in the servlet?

Comment: What is the stack trace? What is "request"? It is nowhere declared. What framework do you use (those annotations are not a part of JRE)? People here are willing to help but they can't read in mind.

Comment: Looks like Java6 to me.  Also stated request is HttpServletRequest. Don't know the answer though ;-)

Comment: We use a proprietary framework within our company.

Comment: The annotations are jersey (for rest)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Context HttpServletRequest request` as an argument of the resource method.
So it should be something like this:

```
public Response postMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request){

    // rest of the code

}
```